# can jasmine's and.returnValue method take into acount a parameter

Tags: angular, jasmine

In my component's ngOnInit I'm doing:

```
this.thing = this._service.foo('a');
this.otherThing = this._service.foo('b');
```

In my test I am using a mock of `service` created like this :

```
mockService = jasmine.createSpyObj('Service', ['foo']);
```

How can I control the values returned by my mock when calling it with `'a'` or `'b'` ?
Because if I do

```
mockService.foo.and.returnValue('value');
```

It will return the same thing when called with `'a'` or `'b'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `and.callFake()`

```
mockService.foo.and.callFake(function (arg) {
    if (arg == "a") {
        return "value1";
    } else {
        return "value2";
    }
    // or whatever
});
```